# why this function addStuent() doesn't return what i expect in python

Tags: python, class, oop

i have a python class that called student.py where it contains attributes and methods  one of these method is called **addStudent(self,name,age)**. it takes 2 arguments.

the problem is this function display the name and the age of the new student using the setter method.

but the console display this :

**None is a new student and he/she has None years old**

where None  MUST BE THE NAME AND THE AGE

## student.py

```
class student():
    def __init__(self,name,age, grade):
        self.stdName=name
        self.stdAge = age
        self.stdGrade = grade

    def getName(self):
        print("the student name {}".format(self.stdName))

    def setName(self,Name):
        self.stdName = Name

    def getAge(self):
        print("the student age :{}".format(self.stdAge))

    def setAge(self, Age):
        self.stdAge = Age

    def getGrade(self):
        print("the student {0}, have a grade {1}".format(self.stdName,self.stdGrade))

        if self.stdGrade<2.5:
            print("you failed")
        elif self.stdGrade>2.5:
            print("good job continue")
        elif self.stdGrade == 5.0:
            print("you are a honor student")

    def setGrade(self,Grade):
        self.stdGrade = Grade


    def getTheAVG(self,initial,*grades):

        value = initial
        for item in grades:
            value+=float(item)
            return value/(len(grades)+1)

        print("Average of the student is " + str((grades)))

    def addStudent(self,name,age):
        print("{0} is a new student and he/she has {1} years old"
              .format(self.setName(name),self.setAge(age)))


std1 = student("georges", 17, 3.4)
std1.getName()
std1.getAge()
std1.getGrade()
std1.addStudent("jiji",12)

std1.getTheAVG(2.4,5.0,4.6,2.2,1.2)
```

Comment: because `self.setName` doesn't return anything?

Comment: It doesn't return what you expect because you have no `return` statement in your function, which therefore returns `None`

Comment: okk i got it can any one make an answer in order to make it correct answer

Comment: It is your design that is wrong. Why do you have an `addStudent` method - you should call the constructor again to add a new student object.  In your `addStudent` method you are trying to call setter methods in a `print` statement where you should call getters.

Your getter methods should just get (return) values, not `print` them - you can always use `__str__` if you need to.  If they need to be printed then that should be up to the user code.  Your setter methods should ONLY set.  Be clear that functions should do only ONE thing.

Comment: Also, your `getTheAVG` method should not be an object method since it does not use `self` anywhere.

Comment: @cdarke i have this exercise where i need to create a student CLASS and a class CLASS.

i am new to oop so i do not know what are the methods that i can added to the student and class CLASS and how to make the class conssist of the student class as a list of student objects

Comment: I suggest that a class called CLASS is horribly confusing, call it something else. like StudentGroup, for example.  A StudentGroup object can hold a list of Student (you should capitalise class names) objects.  That's where the `getTheAVG` method should be.

Answer (score 2):

You function is not returning a value hence it is getting `None`. You can do this.

```
def setAge(self, Age):
        self.stdAge = Age
        return self.stdAge
```

But, Having said it is a setter method from a design point of view you won't expect a `setter` function to return any value

Answer (score 1):

Your `print` relies on the return values of two methods that don't return anything. Either have the`setName` and `setAge` methods return the value they set, or just use the attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
class student():
    def __init__(self,name,age, grade):
        self.stdName=name
        self.stdAge = age
        self.stdGrade = grade

    def getName(self):
        print("the student name {}".format(self.stdName))

    def setName(self,Name):
        self.stdName = Name
        return self.stdName

    def getAge(self):
        print("the student age :{}".format(self.stdAge))

    def setAge(self, Age):
        self.stdAge = Age
        return self.stdAge

    def getGrade(self):
        print("the student {0}, have a grade {1}".format(self.stdName,self.stdGrade))

        if self.stdGrade<2.5:
            print("you failed")
        elif self.stdGrade>2.5:
            print("good job continue")
        elif self.stdGrade == 5.0:
            print("you are a honor student")

    def setGrade(self,Grade):
        self.stdGrade = Grade


    def getTheAVG(self,initial,*grades):

        value = initial
        for item in grades:
            value+=float(item)
            return value/(len(grades)+1)

        print("Average of the student is " + str((grades)))

    def addStudent(self, name, age):
        print("{0} is a new student and he/she has {1} years old"
              .format(self.setName(name), self.setAge(age)))


std1 = student("georges", 17, 3.4)
std1.getName()
std1.getAge()
std1.getGrade()
std1.addStudent("jiji",12)

std1.getTheAVG(2.4,5.0,4.6,2.2,1.2)
```

This will give you your desired output.

**Note:** Your function is not returning a value thats way it give you `None` but from a design point of view as your method is a setter method and setter methods don't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your setter method to return something, do something like this

```
class Student:

def setName(self,Name):
    self.stdName = Name
    return self.stdName

def setAge(self, Age):
    self.stdAge = Age
    return self.stdAge
```

Comment: what  methods can i added to the student class ?

Comment: This is poor design, setters should set, not get as well.

Comment: @PytLeb, Please try to change the code design, as everyone is pointing and telling the same thing, you can't return some value in setter method, It's better to store your data in dictionary or list which you can print anytime whenever you add new data.